# Is the Inspire 1 a good drone starter aircraft?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

First of all, I'm not totally positive that this will be well received here; I did read the related meta, but am unsure. [I have also asked the question in support of the new Drone SE.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63158/diy-drones/81453#81453)

I'm new to drones, and I've been researching. Would it be a bad idea to start out as a beginner with the Inspire 1 (sort of the cutting edge, top of the line, nicest looking drone out there)?

I read somewhere that with Drones, unlike normal RC aircraft, (and large aircraft perhaps) the higher the price, the *easier* the flying. I'm worried about whether or not getting a very high end drone as my first one might prove a foolish investment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this question will remain open long but here's my $0.02:

---

You will **definitely want to learn to fly a cheap quadcopter** before going expensive. Quadcopters are not *that* easy to fly (there is a lot going on at the same time: 6 degrees of freedom being controlled in a changing frame of reference depending on orientation to a stationary pilot).

I crashed my cheap one a lot learning to fly it despite it being pretty stable, but it is robust and takes a good beating. A cheap one is a very low risk and pain compared to the one you're looking at: You're not going have to break a lot on the expensive one to recoup the investment of becoming acquainted to quadcopters before you started.

Quadcopters may become a little 'smarter' as you go more expensive and be more stable, but it still requires good piloting.